# java.nio.file package not detecting directory changes

Tags: java, nio

I want to detect files being written to a directory and so thought the Java NIO package would be suitable. However, I've ran their tester code (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java)
and it will only detect file changes made by the machine running the script.
i.e. we have multiple servers running which share a number of mounted drives. If I log into one of these servers, run the test code, log into the same machine again via another terminal and make changes to the directory I'm watching, these changes will be detected. However, if I log into a different server, these changes are not. Is this a fundamental problem with NIO, in which case is there something else I should use, or is there a workaround?

Comment: sorry- didn't mean to be rude, both answers were useful.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It kinda tries to warn you: [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)

> #### Platform dependencies
>
> [...]
>
> If a watched file is not located on a local storage device then it is
>   implementation specific if changes to the file can be detected. In
>   particular, it is not required that changes to files carried out on
>   remote systems be detected.

I'm afraid you'll need to periodically poll manually.

Comment: Ah, not mentioned in the tutorial! ok, thanks I'll do it manually then. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

That isn't necessarily a problem a probem of Java NIO.

It very much depends on the overall stack, as in: which file systems are used, and which operating systems are running on your servers.

Example: when you have one server X create a new file on a shared file system, such as AFS for example, then *another* server looking at the shared directory might *only* see that there is a new file. But as long as the file is written to, you need to log into X to see the latest writes. Only when the writing process is done, and closes the file, the written content becomes *visible* to other servers.

So, as said, the real answer is to research the characteristics of the the file system / server OS(es) you are using. Which nicely aligns/explains what the other answer is stating: Java NIO can't give you generic guarantees, because the exact behavior is implementation specific.